# Equating two definitions of Zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

The Zeta function $\zeta(s)$ is defined as following
$$
\zeta(s)=1+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}+\frac1{4^s}+\frac1{5^s}+\cdots=\sum_{n=1}\frac1{n^s}
$$
Now it has been shown that
$$
\tag1 \zeta(s)=\frac{\eta(s)}{1-\frac 1{2^s}\cdot 2}
$$
$$
\eta(s)=1-\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}-\frac1{4^s}+\frac1{5^s}- \cdots=\sum_{n=1}(-1)^n\left(-\frac1{n^s}\right)
$$
Now this is my first question: **Is the following true?**

$$
\tag2 \eta(s)\ + 2\cdot \left(\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{4^s}+\frac1{6^s}+\frac1{8^s}+\cdots \right)= \zeta (s)
$$

**And so can we equate $(1)$ and $(2)$?** It would look something like
$$
\eta(s)\ + 2\cdot \left(1+\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{4^s}+\frac1{6^s}+\frac1{8^s}+\cdots \right)=\frac{\eta(s)}{1-\frac 1{2^s}\cdot 2}
$$

Comment: Note that those series expansions are valid only for $\Re s>1$. It looks to me like (2) is not quite right. Something very much like (2) is true. Seems to me the problem is you missed a minus sign: If we saw $\left(\frac1{n^s}\right)$ in the definition of $\eta$ instead of $\left(\frac1{-n^s}\right)$ then your formula would be correct. Regarding your last question: Yes, if $A=B$ and $A=C$ then $B=C$ (reference: Euclid, _Elements_).

Comment: I think that you just arrive at some reformulation of $(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)=\eta(s)$, so nothing new.